# Zsh tab completions not working as desired for partial paths

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I want case-insensitive fuzzy completion for files and directories in `zsh`. After reading the manual for a few hours, this is what I came up with:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:globbed-files' matcher 'r:|?=** m:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:local-directories' matcher 'r:|?=** m:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:directories' matcher 'r:|?=** m:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}'
```

Additionally, I want pressing `TAB` once to display possible completions, only modifying what I have typed if there is exactly one completion. Then pressing `TAB` a second time should put me into "menu completion" mode. Based on the manuals, I came up with this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
```

Now everything works as it should except in one circumstance. I have two folders `Desktop` and `.rstudio-desktop` in my home directory. Since I have `setopt globdots`, I expect typing the following:

```
$ cd ~/dktop<TAB>
```

to leave my command as entered, and display as completion candidates `Desktop` and `.rstudio-desktop`. Instead, it *removes* `dktop`, leaving me with the following:

```
$ cd ~/
```

I have looked at all of the relevant manuals, guides, Stack Exchange questions, and various other sources. But whatever I do, I can't make this work.

Interestingly, though, if I'm *in* the home directory and type the following then everything works as expected:

```
$ cd dktop<TAB>
```

That is, it's only a problem with non-leading segments of paths (and you can see with `C-x h` that this corresponds to the `directories` tag rather than the `local-directories` tag being used).

For easy reproducibility, [here](https://gist.github.com/raxod502/90180c1292d691f4cc5724c16826274a) is a `~/.zshrc` that will reproduce the situation and behavior described above (tested on a fresh El Capitan virtual machine with `zsh` from Homebrew).

Comment: Can't reproduce. `zsh 5.3.1` on `Arch Linux`. `cd ~/dktop<tab>` yields `cd ~/Desktop`.

Comment: @PythonNut With `zsh 5.3.1` on OS X the issue does reproduce. It's interesting that there is a difference between the operating systems.

Comment: @PythonNut Actually, I bet this is because Linux is case-sensitive and macOS is case-insensitive.

Comment: Just as a friendly reminder not all Macs / macOS are case-insensitive it depends on wether your disk is formated case-insensitive or not.

Comment: It might've been a bug that has been fixed, because it works correctly for me now with [tag:zsh] 5.8 on [tag:macOS].

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to do:

```
bindkey "^I" expand-word
```

This will cause tab to expand `~/` to the absolute path.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how this relates in any way to fuzzy tab completions, or to solving the problem outlined above. If I do as you suggest, then pressing TAB will give me `cd /Users/raxod502/dktop`, and completion is disabled.

Comment: @RadonRosborough The hope was that by expanding `~/` to its absolute path that fuzzy completion would start working. It seemed like one of those cases where the problem is that it evaluates it once but you actually need it to evaluate twice to work, so having the absolute path instead of `~/` would mean it'd go back to only needing one evaluation. But crap, I'm sorry, I forgot that bindkey replaces old bindings, and I can't find anything that says if it's even possible to bindkey two functions to one key.

Without my bindkey, does your completion work as intended when given absolute paths?

Comment: No. It makes no difference whether the input path is `~/dktop` or `/Users/raxod502/dktop`; the result is the same, namely that `dktop` is deleted when I press TAB.